# Android matrix rotation of bitmap change center

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-canvas, ondraw

I've got a strange problem with `Bitmap` rotation.
That's my code:

in `onDraw` method

```
int cx_gear_big = (getWidth() - gear_big.getWidth()) >> 1;
int cy_gears_big = (getHeight() - gear_big.getHeight()) >> 1;
canvas.drawBitmap(rotateGear(gear_big, bigGearAngle), cx_gear_big,cy_gears_big, null);
```

That's my method which returns rotated `Bitmap`:

```
  public static Bitmap rotateGear(Bitmap source, int angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    }
```

I have few gears in my `canvas`, but it doesn't really matter.

My problem is:

When I'm rotating my `Bitmap` (a gear) it moves down and left (it depends on the angle of rotation) then it comes back...
Where can my problem be in this case?

UPD:
Translation of `Bitmap` is not linear. It's like bouncing.

Comment: Try using `setRotate()` instead of `postRotate()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRotate%28float%29

Comment: don't work
same problem

Comment: More specific postRotate around a point.  setRotate(float degrees, float px, float py)
Set the matrix to rotate by the specified number of degrees, with a pivot point at (px, py).  I think 0,0 is top left of image so px,py is width/2, height/2

Comment: Just me but I would make all the images in the background and save to sdcard.  Then buffer them loading the next image while displaying the current image.

Comment: Don't do that,  don't use `Bitmap.createBitmap` in order to draw rotated Bitmap,  use `Canvas.drawBitmap` with a Matrix parameter instead

Comment: any of your comments not helpful, sorry.
Something else?

Comment: As i said use `Canvas.drawBitmap` with a Matrix parameter, this is a standard way of drawing transformed Bitmap

Comment: @pskink, i try it also, result the same... i'm really don't understand where can be problem because class code is minimal.

Comment: m.postTranslate(100,100) m.postRotate(20,100,100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ideal way to solve this problem is translate matrix before rotation and translate it back. Code example:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
float px = getWidth()/2;
float py = getHeight()/2;
m.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
m.postRotate(angle);
m.postTranslate(px, py);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, null);
```

Comment: It took me forever to figure out that the pivot (first `Matrix.postTranslate`) has to be negative because it seems that the initial pivot is in the center. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
matrix.setRotate(angle, bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2);
```